# android : Error on Shading Language with opengl es2.0 on android 2.2

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I have a problem with application. is a simple application atm using opengl es2.0 which running on android 2.2 device HTC sense. I can running the application on my 4.0.3 emulator as well as my device which running android 4.0.

When running on android 2.2, i have this error:

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error compiling shader: 
SimpleShader.loadShader(SimpleShader.java:87)
SimpleShader.<init>(SimpleShader.java:54)
etc
```

I assumed that the device can run android 2.2 as the document told [LINKS TO DOCUMENTATION](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html), but not sure about the shader part though.

Here is my shader code:

```
String verticesShader =
        "uniform mat4 uScreen;\n" +    
        "attribute vec2 aPosition;\n" +
        "attribute vec3 aColor;\n" +
        "attribute vec2 aTexPos; \n" +
        "varying vec2 vTexPos; \n" + 
        "varying vec3 vColor;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        " vTexPos = aTexPos; \n" +  
        " gl_Position = uScreen * vec4(aPosition.xy, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
        "  vColor = aColor;\n" +
        "}";

      // Our fragment shader. Just return vColor.
      // If you look at this source and just said 'WTF?', remember
      // that all the attributes are defined in the VERTEX shader and
      // all the 'varying' vars are considered OUTPUT of vertex shader
      // and INPUT of the fragment shader. Here we just use the color
      // we received and add a alpha value of 1.
      String fragmentShader =
        "uniform float uUseTexture; \n" +
        "uniform float uAlpha; \n" +
        "uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n"+
        "varying vec2 vTexPos; \n" +
        "varying vec3 vColor;\n" + 
        "void main(void)\n" +
        "{\n" + 
        " if ( uUseTexture != 1.0 ) \n" +
        "  gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor.xyz, 1); \n" +
        " else \n" +
        "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexPos); \n" +
        " gl_FragColor.a *= uAlpha;" +
        //"  gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor.xyz, 1);\n" +
        "}";

private int loadShader(int shader, String shaderSrc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int handle = GLES20.glCreateShader(shader);

    if (handle == GLES20.GL_FALSE)
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating shader!");

    GLES20.glShaderSource(handle, shaderSrc);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(handle);

    int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(handle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

    if (compileStatus[0] ==0)
      {
        String error = GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(handle);
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(handle);
        throw new RuntimeException("Error compiling shader: " + error);
      }
      else
        return handle;

}
```

The application works fine on my latest device with android 4.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered checking your OpenGL ES GLSL version on both the android 2.2 device and the android 4.0+ device?
You can print it with `GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)`.

Comment: Sorry, I had use this on my eclipse but couldn't recognized the GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION enum type

Comment: Sorry I found it ... i need to call GLES20.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION

Comment: I am not sure this might help much but I'm just looking into the possibility that you might be compiling shaders on an older GLSL version on your android 2.3 device.

Comment: Could you point out on which line in your vertex/fragment shader you get the error?

Comment: The line : throw new RuntimeException("Error compiling shader: " + error); in above code. How do I translate the above shader language to a previous version? I am new to this.

Comment: I found my problem... forgot to add the clamp to edge for the texture parameter